# Cannot access a disposed object error

Tags: c#, winforms

I am getting the error message **Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'ApplicationProperties'.** when I tryo to re-open a form after closing it. I have noticed this is from exiting forms, and exiting is **"Disposing"** of them, so I have put the following code in all of my accept buttons, and cancel buttons (any button that closes a form).

```
 this.Hide(); 
 this.Parent = null;
```

This code is just hiding the form. **Not closing the form.**

So what my problem is, is that when I click the 'x' button on the form, then try to re-open the form I still get the error message. I have tried a couple differnet ways to modify the exiting funciton of the form such as:

```
    private void ApplicationProperties_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        //Hiding the window, because closing it makes the window unaccessible.
        this.Hide();
        this.Parent = null;
    }
```

But this has brought me no luck. I was wondering if anyone knows how to solve this problem. Here is the code that is working for me inside my cancel and accept buttons. It is the same for all of my buttons that close forms.

```
    private void OptionsCancelbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Hiding the window, because closing it makes the window unaccessible.
        this.Hide();
        this.Parent = null;
    }
```

I have declared the instance at the top of my class on form1, and have a button inside form1 that opens form2.

```
public partial class MainBox : Form
{
    //Making a name for the ApplicationProperties form. It can be opened when called.
    ApplicationProperties ApplicationPropertiesWindow = new ApplicationProperties();
    private void ApplicationPropertiesbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Show the properties window.
        ApplicationPropertiesWindow.Show();
    }//End ApplicationProperties button.
 }
```

After I close the program with the 'x' button on the second form I cannot access form2 again because of the error message firing at `ApplicationPropertiesWindow.Show();`

Inside form2 I have the following code:

```
public partial class ApplicationProperties : Form
{
    //Creates and sets the instance MainBoxWindow.
    public MainBox MainBoxWindow { get; set; }
```

Comment: Can you show the code that is failing in the way you describe at the *beginning* of the question? That's the one that really needs fixing, rather than your attempt to hack around it.

Comment: @CodyGray I have updated the question showing where the error fires.

Comment: What's the desired behavior? You're either trying to access whatever ApplicationProperties object you already disposed, or you're unintentionally disposing it in your code somewhere. Either initialize a new ApplicationProperties object, or find where you're disposing it and remove the code if you want that object to remain in memory. Check the definition of the class, or do a find on Dispose

Comment: I am trying to access the object, and it is getting disposed when I click the 'x' button.

Comment: I realize that. What I'm saying is, do you 'want' the object to be disposed, or do you want it to persist? When you load the ApplicationProperties form, are you initializing it with values that are stored elsewhere? Or do they disappear when the user closes the form forever, and thats ok? The right answer depends on how you want the application to behave in YOUR context. You can get rid of the default Dispose method as a quick fix, but that means the object will persist in memory till you manually dispose it or the parent closes.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. There are other values saved through that form, onto a .xml file. So I think that if it where to get disposed that it would be okay, and I could just laod the .xml every time the form is opened. Also, I searched my code for Dispose and nothing came up.

Comment: In that case, it would probably be fine to just initialize a new ApplicationsProperty object whenever you want to reload it. I'm purely speculating that you're trying to use the same identifier cause I don't see where you initialize the form above, but if you show us that part of your code we can help if you're not quite sure.

Comment: That is what I have been trying to do, I tried putting the initialization in the button_pressed event to open the form, but that did not work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this in your `FormClosing` event:

```
  private void ApplicationProperties_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
  {
        //Hiding the window, because closing it makes the window unaccessible.
        this.Hide();
        this.Parent = null;
        e.Cancel = true; //hides the form, cancels closing event
   }
```

cause right now it is still closing the form, thus still causing the error.

Comment: I gave it a try, but no luck.

Comment: Is there anything else running that we are not seeing?

Comment: I may be wrong, but isn't closing the form causing the problem? I need to hide it? I am not 100% sure about it, but that's what I though was happeneing.

Comment: I am not aware of anyhting else that is running. I will update the question with some more info.

Comment: e.Cancel prevents the form from closing. What is this.Parent = null doing?

Comment: This is my boss' code, I am trying to expand on his program, and since that was working on the buttons, I transferred it over to the exit function. If I comment it out it still does not work.

Answer (score 5):

> After I close the program with the 'x' button on the second form I
>   cannot access form2 again because of the error message firing at
>   `ApplicationPropertiesWindow.Show();`

When a form is closed ([`Form.Close`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close.aspx)), the form itself and all of its associated resources are freed. There are only two exceptions to this automatic disposal, as noted in the documentation:

1. The form is part of a MDI application and *not* visible.
2. The form was displayed as a modal dialog using `ShowDialog` (as opposed to `Show`). It is designed this way so that you can access properties of the dialog (e.g. to retrieve user input) after the user has closed it.

In both of these special cases, you are responsible for manually calling the `Dispose` method of the form. The second case is by far the most common (no one really uses the MDI paradigm anymore), and is handled easily with a `using` statement:

```
using (MyDialogBox dlg = new MyDialogBox())
{
    DialogResult result = dlg.ShowModal(this);
    if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        // access members of "dlg", and
        // do whatever the user asked
    }
}  // the Dispose method is automatically called here
```

In your case, as is typical, the call to the `Close` method is closing *and destroying* the form. You already know that you cannot access a disposed object (because it no longer exists!), so that's why you're getting the exception when you try to show it. In order to show the form again after it has been closed, you need to create a new instance of the form class:

```
MyForm frm = new MyForm();
frm.Show();
// ...
frm.Close();
```

This is really the best method. A new instance of the form will be identical to the one you're closing because it was created from the same class. You would do best to start thinking in object-oriented terms and avoid singleton-based designs whenever possible. Each form that shows up on the screen is a new, independent *object*. Once that object is closed and destroyed, you cannot use it any longer. If you want to use it again, you need to create a new object and display it.

The `Hide` method is more of a hack, useful only when you want to temporarily hide the current instance of a form while still retaining its state (e.g., the values of its member properties, its control states, etc.). This works only with singleton objects that will never be destroyed, and must be carefully designed and maintained. It also means that this form object consumes resources all the time, whether it is being used or not, which is wasteful.

If you *must* do this, you'll need to track down what is causing your form instance to be disposed. Without seeing all of your code, it's hard for me to do anything but guess at where the problem might be. It is likely related to your use of the `AcceptButton` and/or `CancelButton` properties. Either way, the best and cleanest solution is to override the [`OnFormClosing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onformclosing.aspx) method and prevent your form from ever being closed. You'll hide it instead:

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    protected virtual void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        // Prevent the form from closing.
        e.Cancel = true;

        // Hide it instead.
        this.Hide();
    }

    // ...other code in your form class
}
```

The advantage of this is that you only have to have the code in *one* place, local to the responsible class, rather than exposed to external code and scattered throughout your application. And of course, it also prevents the form from ever being closed by framework code outside of your control.

I have no idea why you're setting the `Parent` property to `null`. A top-level window (which is what all forms are) can never have a parent. Only child windows (e.g. controls) have parents. It *can* have an owner, but it will not necessarily. It depends on whether you pass an owner window as an argument when calling the `Show` method.

Answer (score 3):

First remove this.Parent=null bcose this is not required when you hiding the Form

Now when you hiding the Form and if you still want to access this Form store form in static var . Bcous when object is no longer in use garbage collector dispose it and it will no longer available .

Comment: How do I go about that?

Comment: I am answering this question by my cell phone . So please consider if I not written currently

Comment: How do I store the form in a static var?

Comment: Creat a var *** public static Form yourForm ; *** and then reference your form to this var

Comment: That is conflicting with the instance I already have up between the two forms.

Comment: Create a separate static public class and put this var in this class or if you have more than one Form use more var .

Comment: Okay, I will give that a try.

Comment: Ok . It will work properly If not . tomorrow when I use my PC I will probably explain you and give you the code . Best of luck

Answer (score 3):

The problem, at least perhaps part of it, looks like a bit of class interdependence.

When you initialize an `ApplicationProperties` instance, you're creating a reference to a `MainBox` object, but in the definition of the `MainBox` class, you're creating a new `ApplicationsProperties` object, which references a `MainBox`.... I'm even confusing myself. Is `MainBox` your parent form, the one that loads when you start the application?

I wouldn't be surprised if some stuff in `MainBox` is getting destroyed inadvertently if you set a reference to it in the `ApplicationProperites` class... which is disposing when you click "X". Again, this is an educated guess; I'm not sure if that's the reason but even if the code isn't *wrong* per se, it looks quirky to me.

If you want your `ApplicationProperties` window to last forever and to simplify things, just initialize a static instance of it at the beginning of whatever form is going to persist the duration of your application, and show/hide it similar to what you were attempting originally. If you want to be efficient and fundamental, construct and dispose `ApplicationProperties` whenever you need to let the user modify it, but kill the circular dependency.